# lower_bound in C++ minus vector

Tags: c++, stl

What does the following code do?

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    v[i] = std::lower_bound(prim+1, prim+h+1, val[i]) - prim;
```

Where `prim`,`v` and `val` are vectors of integers.

Comment: O yes, but I do not understand that minus (-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start with reading what the function lower_bound does: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lower_bound/

In this case for each element v[i] in vector v[] we find a vector's prim[] index k with lowest value where prim[k]>=val[i].

Comment: Ok, thank you @agnis!

Answer (score 2):

I think your description is wrong, and `prim` is an iterator or a pointer rather than a vector.

This line is taking the return value of `lower_bound`, which is the same type as the iterator, and subtracting that iterator. That gives you an index into the container that `prim` refers to.